# Accordion not closing other open divs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have done research and to my knowledge data-target is what i need to close down the div, if the other open. In other words I need to open one div at a time. But i think i am unable to do that or cannot make sense on how to open one accordion at a time. Here is my [code](http://codepen.io/codearts/pen/MJVwyB?editors=1000#0)

```
 <a role="button" 
 data-toggle="collapse" 
 data-parent="#accordion" 
 href="#collapseOne" 
 aria-expanded="true"
 aria-controls="collapseOne">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Bootstrap [Collapse API](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-methods) to watch for `show.bs.collapse` event triggers firing, then closing other collapse elements using the `collapse('hide')` method. The code for that would be as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $panels = $('.panel-collapse');

  $panels.on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
    $panels.not(this).collapse('hide');
  });
});
```

Here is an updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPXLNP?editors=1010) also with some updated HTML.

Note, I'd recommend to never have a `row` directly within another `row`, there simply isn't any need for it and can create issues with the grid. Also, you may not need as many `container` classes as you have, you can simply have the wrapping containers to effectively contain the contents.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Sometimes I get lost in Bootstrap documentation.

Comment: I feel you, it can definitely get overwhelming, but once you can navigate through it you find some very exciting things you can do with their API. Hopefully the answer helped.

Comment: What does the `$panel.on` do?

Comment: $panels a variable that is simply storing the `.panel-collapse` items so that they don't get queried/retrieved each time the event fires. jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is a method for attaching events to jQuery elements. `on()` is needed in this case because we are looking for a custom Bootstrap event rather than something standard like `click()` or `focus()`. In this case it will listen for any `show.bs.collapse` events (when panel open is triggered) then execute the anonymous function executing hide on other collapse elements.